# Atraci doesn't play music

Tags: music, youtube

I've installed a very nice YT music player but it won't play any music. I try to run tar.gz file from Atraci site and I've installed it from ppa. This app doesn't work on Ubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome and now, on Xubuntu.

Terminal says:

```
./Atraci 
[13845:0514/191114:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] ""This module is meant to be used by cli. If you want to use ytdl programmatically, visit https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core"", source: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/node_modules/ytdl/index.js (1)
[13845:0514/191115:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] ""failed to fetch poland.json"", source: file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/app.js (1)
[13845:0514/191121:INFO:CONSOLE(23)] ""VIDEOJS:" {"message":"Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The element's readyState is HAVE_NOTHING.","name":"InvalidStateError","code":11,"stack":"Error: Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The element's readyState is HAVE_NOTHING.\n    at Error (native)\n    at t.Kd (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js:105:92)\n    at V (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js:59:80)\n    at t.currentTime (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js:60:150)\n    at PlayTrack (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/app.js:1:8526)\n    at HTMLDivElement.\u003Canonymous\u003E (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/app.js:1:23765)\n    at HTMLDivElement.n.event.dispatch (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3:6404)\n    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3:3179)"} "Video is not ready. (Video.js)"", source: file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js (23)
[13845:0514/191132:INFO:CONSOLE(23)] ""VIDEOJS:" {"message":"Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The element's readyState is HAVE_NOTHING.","name":"InvalidStateError","code":11,"stack":"Error: Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The element's readyState is HAVE_NOTHING.\n    at Error (native)\n    at t.Kd (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js:105:92)\n    at V (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js:59:80)\n    at t.currentTime (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js:60:150)\n    at PlayTrack (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/app.js:1:8526)\n    at HTMLDivElement.\u003Canonymous\u003E (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/app.js:1:23765)\n    at HTMLDivElement.n.event.dispatch (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3:6404)\n    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3:3179)"} "Video is not ready. (Video.js)"", source: file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js (23)
[13845:0514/191139:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] ""failed to fetch poland.json"", source: file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/app.js (1)
[13845:0514/191149:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] ""failed to fetch poland.json"", source: file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/app.js (1)
[13845:0514/191244:INFO:CONSOLE(23)] ""VIDEOJS:" {"message":"Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The element's readyState is HAVE_NOTHING.","name":"InvalidStateError","code":11,"stack":"Error: Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The element's readyState is HAVE_NOTHING.\n    at Error (native)\n    at t.Kd (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js:105:92)\n    at V (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js:59:80)\n    at t.currentTime (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js:60:150)\n    at PlayTrack (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/app.js:1:8526)\n    at HTMLDivElement.\u003Canonymous\u003E (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/app.js:1:23765)\n    at HTMLDivElement.n.event.dispatch (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3:6404)\n    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3:3179)"} "Video is not ready. (Video.js)"", source: file:///tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.2wCqtx/js/vendor/video-js/video.js (23)
```

Comment: Youtube changed its communication protocol (API) with programs so old API won't work. Check out this https://github.com/Atraci/Atraci/issues/266

Comment: So why they realese new versions if the app don't work, the same is with minitube :/ ?

Comment: `smtube` also doesn't work.